# Read CSV File From Sharepoint Using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, xmlhttprequest, vue-component

For some context, I'm looking to read a csv file that is stored on a sharepoint - and I'm looking to do this from the frontend (a vue component) of my vue web application, and display it on that vue.

[This post was really helpful](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/06d7686e-896e-4892-a9f0-ebae2d9ff799/how-to-readwriteupdate-a-csv-file-present-in-an-document-library-using-javascript?forum=sharepointgeneral)

However, I don't make use of jquery anywhere in the application and only need to read the csv file in one part of my code. Therefore, I was wondering how I can go about implementing this with just the XMLHttpRequest API as opposed to jquery's AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question completely, but here is what I think might be the answer:

## using XMLHttpRequest():

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

       // in here you basically manipulate your dom with fetched data or call on functions.
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "yourApiUrl", true);
xhttp.send();
```

## JSON:

```js
let url = 'https://example.com';

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(out =>
  console.log('My data here', out))
.catch(err => throw err);
```

### JSON is Like XML Because

- Both JSON and XML are "self describing" (human readable)
- Both JSON and XML are hierarchical (values within values)
- Both JSON and XML can be parsed and used by lots of programming languages
- Both JSON and XML can be fetched with an XMLHttpRequest

### JSON is Unlike XML Because

- JSON doesn't use end tag
- JSON is shorter
- JSON is quicker to read and write
- JSON can use arrays

#### The biggest difference is:

**XML has to be parsed with an XML parser. JSON can be parsed by a standard JavaScript function.**

### Why JSON is Better Than XML

> XML is much more difficult to parse than JSON.
> JSON is parsed into a ready-to-use JavaScript object.

**Source:** [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp)